How to make a SQL Query to filter records based on priority conditions?
I am facing difficulties in a SQL query where I need to filter records based on a priority condition. If a record meets a priority condition (rn = 1), it should be returned, but if not, then checking for a secondary condition (rn2 = 1) should be done. What is the best way to structure this query?
Look at the code:
CTE_aux AS (
  SELECT *,
    CASE 
      WHEN status LIKE '%SIGNED%' THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END AS rn
  FROM Principal
),
CTE_aux2 AS (
  SELECT *,
    CASE 
      WHEN rn = 0 and status = 'ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS rn2
 FROM CTE_aux
),
Consulta2 AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM CTE_aux2  
  WHERE rn = 1 OR (rn = 0 AND rn2 = 1)
)

If the status is '%SIGNED%' RN = 1 it is OK, it must be returned. Now if it is RN = 0, a check is made to see if the status is ENDORSEMENT_SUCESS, if so, RN2 = returns 1.
So, I want the items that received RN =1 and the items that received RN = 0 and RN2 = 1 to be shown.
This is what results:
advertiser_id   credito_id   contract_id    status         rn rn2
dfb03613         5225           1409   ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS  0  1
dfb03613           5225        1409     CONTRACTS_SIGNED   1  0

But this was not supposed to happen because if RN=1 it should not enter RN=2. STATUS SIGNED is checked first

Please add some sample data and output.

"So, I want the items that received RN =1 and the items that received RN = 0 and RN2 = 1 to be shown." <- Your example output you say is not suppoed to happen, matches exactly with what you say you want in this statement. It is not clear to me what you want. But this was not supposed to happen because if RN=1 it should not enter RN=2 <-- What does RN=1 and RN=2 mean here? Do you mean rn1 and rn2 and you are using different language? Please clarify.

@JNevill
'RN' is just an aelatory name I created for an "accountant".
If the RN=1 in the first CTE it should not enter the second, as the second only checks those who received RN=0, understand? Therefore, it should be impossible for someone with RN = 1 to also have RN2 = 1, you know? Since to have RN2=1 you need to have RN=0

You say it should be impossible for someone with rn1 of  1 to have rn2 also equal 1, but your logic for rn2 literally says CASE WHEN rn = 1 then 1. I'm still confused. Also the output data you shared in your last edit doesn't show that event occurring either. There are two records and with both either rn1 or rn2 has a value of 1 or 0, but not both in the same record.

Sorry! I entered the wrong code. Now I fixed it!!
RN2 must only verify those who receive RN=0. However, it is happening that those who received RN=1 are checked in RN2. RN2 is only for those who received RN=0
It is happening that the same ID receives RN=1 and receives RN2 = 1. Which should be impossible, since only those who have RN = 0 receive RN2 = 1

I don't understand how in the first case it receives RN=1 and in the second case it receives RN = 0. When checking the SIGNED in the first CTE the ID should not be looked at again. How do I do that? I don't know if I'm being clear

Once Status = SIGNED it receives RN=1 and bye. It should not be analyzed again to receive RN2

The problem is that after an advertiser_id is marked with RN=1, it is still showing up in the check for RN2. How can I ensure that RN2 is only applied to IDs that have been assigned RN=0?

Can you share an example record that ends up having an rn1=1 AND rn2=1. I just don't see how it's possible given your updated code. The only three combinations this can output for rn1, rn2 is 0,1, 1,0, or 0,0.

I agree with @JNevill. With your current code and output, you mentioned everything is looking good. It will not show rn=1 and rn2=1 in the output.


Score the results using CASE; 2) Partition and Sort them using OVER; 3) Select the first from each partition using WHERE. Easy peasy.


@The Impaler It's not that easy. I think I'm not explaining it properly because English is not my native language.
But note that it's the same person, however, the STATUS changes. The same person goes through various status phases. I want that if this person already has SIGNED status, it shouldn't even check if they also have the other status. But the operating system checks because when the status changes, it treats it as if it were a different object, you know?

Note that there is a duplication of IDs with different statuses. It is possible for there to be a THIAGO who is both SIGNED and another THIAGO (the same one) with ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS. I want that when the SIGNED Thiago is checked, it doesn't check the other THIAGO with ENDORSEMENT status.

@ThiagoMelo I think I may see the solution. However, it seems I don't understand all the subtleties for all cases. Can you add a few rows of sample data and the expected result?

As folks in the comments I also don't see the problem you are facing. Please clarify if this SQL statement doesn't return what you need.
WITH data AS (
SELECT
  *,
  CASE 
    WHEN status LIKE '%SIGNED%' THEN 1
    WHEN status = 'ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS' THEN 2
  END AS rn,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE 
                    WHEN status LIKE                     '%SIGNED%' THEN 1
                    WHEN status =                     'ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS'                     THEN 2 END) AS row_n
FROM Principal
WHERE (status LIKE '%SIGNED%' OR status = 'ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS')
)

SELECT * FROM data
WHERE row_n = 1

You can easily split rn into two fields if needed.

Note that there is a duplication of IDs with different statuses. It is possible for there to be a THIAGO who is both SIGNED and another THIAGO (the same one) with ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS. I want that when the SIGNED Thiago is checked, it doesn't check the other THIAGO with ENDORSEMENT status.

Okay, now it’s clear for me what is required! Thank you for clarifying. Give me some time to edit the answer.

@ThiagoMelo, could you check the answer above? I’ve edited the code.

the rn column is created in the same selection where you are trying to use it in the ROW_NUMBER() function. In SQL, you cannot reference a calculated column in the same SELECT row where it is created. I will try to adjust this

I changed the answer, please check. It’s about whether Trino allows or not to reference created fields in the same query. Alternatively, you can wrap it with another select query
